# Measurement of the momentum of electron when the momentum is very small

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, measurements, quantum-measurements

In particle physics, it is usually no problem to determine the momentum of a charged particle such as electron, by using something like a pixel detector. This relies on ionization. There is also accompanying energy loss. This measurement is only approximate.

Question1: how do we measure the momentum of a very slow moving single electron?

By "very slow" I mean "way below ionization threshold", e.g. with energy in nano eV.

Question2: is there a fundamental limit on the precision of such measurement?

Note that this has little to do with the uncertainty principle, as we are not trying to measure the coordinates. The uncertainty principle only tells us that the size of the detector must be "large" > h/p.

EDIT:

preliminary conclusion: there is a threshold below which it is impossible to measure the momentum, even as thought experiment.

I am not sure about the following potential techniques:

1. imagine metal-insulator transition in a very large crystal. Perhaps it is possible to engineer arbitrarily small band gap, so that the slow moving electron would trigger this device to conduct a spike of current, and this will be the measurement.
2. attosecond pulses. These strong fields usually very strongly perturb the system under measurement. But perhaps it is possible to bring the electron back to the exact quantum state it was, and still measure the momentum? At least, this is approximately what happens in high harmonic generation.
3. cavity QED systems

Comment: why would one want to do this?Only within materials collective drift velocity has meaning .http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/drift-velocity/

Comment: @annav In some modifications of QED, the manifold of momenta does not exist near 0, i.e. there is a natural boundary in the space of momenta. I was wondering if there is any physical explanation for this. And it looks like there is - there does not exist physical device that can measure momentum blow certain threshold.

Comment: Does your hypothetical lower limit to momentum apply to baryons? There is a robust experimental literature on "ultra-cold neutrons" with energies below 100 neV. There is also an important distinction between "I cannot think of a way to measure very small momenta" versus "very small momenta don't exist."